# How to list records from one table that has atleast one association with other tables?

Tags: postgresql

There are three tables:

1. authors
2. parent_books
3. individual_books

Both parent_books and individual_books have a column called `authors` which contains an array of author ids.

I need to get a list of authors who have an entry in parent_books or individual_books and the count of parent_books and individual_books for each author.

author.id, author.name, pcount , icount

I tried this query

```
  select a.id, a.name, count(pb.id) as pcount from authors as a inner join parent_books pb on pb.authors::UUID[] @> ARRAY[a.id] group by a.id
UNION   
select a.id, a.name, count(ib.id) from authors as a inner join individual_books ib on ib.authors::UUID[] @> ARRAY[a.id] group by a.id
```

pcount and icount are getting overwritten, please help?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output. It will help us to recreate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me remark that using arrays here is a bad database design. You should use a table rather than an array to establish the relationship between books and authors.

That said, you could use an outer query to aggregate the values:

```
SELECT id, name,
       sum(pcount) AS pcount,
       sum(icount) AS icount
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.name,
             count(pb.id) as pcount,
             BIGINT '0' AS icount
      FROM authors AS a
         INNER JOIN parent_books pb
            ON pb.authors::UUID[] @> ARRAY[a.id]
      GROUP BY a.id
      UNION ALL  
      SELECT a.id, a.name,
             BIGINT '0' AS pcount,
             count(ib.id) AS icount
      FROM authors AS a
         INNER JOIN individual_books ib
            ON ib.authors::UUID[] @> ARRAY[a.id]
      GROUP BY a.id) AS q
GROUP BY id, name;
```